# How to use a concern in a Rails initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby on Rails project I have a concern `app/controllers/concerns/common.rb`:

```
module Common
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  private

  def foo
  end

end
```

I want to use its `foo` function inside `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  foo
  ...
end
```

For now I failed to somehow load `common.rb` inside `config/initializers/devise.rb` - how to do it?

Currently I'm using a workaround - I define the `foo` function inside `config/application.rb` and it works, but it breaks the DRY principles.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you could include your concern inside the devise config:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  include Common
  foo
  # ...
end
```

That way how ever you're including the method on ruby's main object / top level context.

Alternatively you could extend 'config' (= Devise) with your module, and call the method foo on config.

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.send(:extend, Common)
  config.foo
  # ...
end
```

To make this work however you would need to make foo a public method, otherwise you won't be able to call it like that.

If you're overall goal is to avoid code duplication it is hard to tell you what the best solution would be, without knowing more about what you want to achieve, e.g. what shared code you want to extract from your devise config.